# Match exact word with new lines anywhere using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match following patterns using JavaScript programming language?

sample (not sample in sampleword)

sam\nple

sa\nmple

I used \b for boundaries for full word match.
I'm trying to find an efficient way to do newline match anywhere in the word.
For case 2: \bsam[\s\S]ple\b  works.
The same can be adapted for case3 as well to match.

But, Is there a way to have single pattern match all of those ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide relevant parts of your code, so we have something to start from.

Comment: Consider looking into string functions and/or regular expressions and come back to this.

Comment: I just gave more information in the question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're asking how to match a string with a single optional space *anywhere* in the string? If so, that looks like this:

```
function getRegEx(word) {
  var patterns = word.split('').map(function (letter, index) {
    return (
      word.slice(0, index) +
      '\\s?' +
      word.slice(index)
    )
  })
  patterns.shift()
  return new RegExp('^' + patterns.join('|') + '$');
}

getRegEx('pattern').test('pat tern') // --> true
```

However, if there can be multiple spaces in the string (as in 's amp le'), then it would be as follows:

```
function getRegEx(word) {
  word = word.split('')
  word = word.map(function (letter) {
    return letter + '\\s?'
  })
  return new RegExp('^' + word.join('') + '$')
}

getRegEx('pattern').test('pat tern') // --> true
```

**Per OP's request (see comments):**

If you want to look for an indefinite number of space characters, pass true to the following function (as the second param). Otherwise, it'll just find one:

```
function getRegEx(word, mult) {
  var spaceCount = mult ? '*' : '?'
  word = word.split('')
  word = word.map(function (letter) {
    return letter + '\\s' + spaceCount
  })
  return new RegExp('^' + word.join('') + '$')
}

getRegEx('pattern', true).test('pat     tern') // --> true
```

If you wish to specify where in the pattern spaces may appear, that can be done as follows:

```
function getRegEx(word, mult) {
  word = word.split('')
  var spaceCount = mult ? '*' : '?'
  var positions = []
  word.forEach(function (char, index) {
    if (char === ' ') positions.push(index)
  })
  positions.forEach(function (pos) {
    word.splice(pos, 1, '\\s' + spaceCount)
  })
  return new RegExp('^' + word.join('') + '$')
}
```

Put a space in your pattern string wherever you want there to be spaces matched. As in:

`getRegEx('p at tern', true).test('p   at     tern') // --> true`

Comment: There is no need to place just one construct into a character class unless you plan to add more symbols to it.

Comment: The brackets are not necessary but do no harm. I actually thought it was clearer when looking at the RegExp.source string. But have it your way.

Comment: Not that I have a problem doing this, But, Is there a way I can specify in the pattern itself to look for 0 or more space characters anywhere in the word?

Comment: I need a little clarification: do you mean you want to specify where an indefinite number of spaces appear? Or can they be anywhere in the string, and there can be an indefinite number of them? -- I tried to provide both ways in the latest edit.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I understood the solution. I just wanted to know if there's a way in regex to mention (by using groups or something like that) that a space can occur anywhere indefinite no of times in a given word. This way I want to avoid constructing pattern dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `\n` using `replace` and compare that to `sample` using word boundaries:

```
/\bsample\b/i.test('sa\nmple'.replace(/\n/g, ''))
true
/\bsample\b/i.test('sam\nple'.replace(/\n/g, ''))
true
/\bsample\b/i.test('sample'.replace(/\n/g, ''))
true
/\bsample\b/i.test('sample'.replace(/\n/g, ''))
true
/\bsample\b/i.test('some sam\nple'.replace(/\n/g, ''))
true
\bsample\b/i.test('sam\nples'.replace(/\n/g, ''))
false
```